# How to make my website appear in google search

Tags: search, web, keyword, meta

I made the meta tags in my website and when I search on my website using the keywords that I wrote in my pages the site doesn't appear. I wrote www.mysite.com in google search but it didn't work either.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about SEO and SEO questions belong on [webmasters.se]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?pli=1 but there is no guarantee.